# How do i send a result from an sql query to a specific email on daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How do i send a result from an sql query or the output of a stored procedure to a specific email on daily basis. I have Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2008 Server.

My Query is like this :

```
SELECT Ename, COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM emp
GROUP BY Ename
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Whenever the query returns result for TotalCount Sql server should send the mail.

Comment: You would need to make sure your server is set up to send emails, then ideally create a stored procedure that is executed on a schedule by a server agent job

Comment: I was going to say you could make an SSRS report and then create a subscription, but it looks like this is an occasional thing

Answer (score 1):

The simple way, assuming you have DBMail set up, is to put this script into the step of a SQL Agent job:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@recipients = 'email@address.com',
@query = 'SELECT Ename, COUNT(*) TotalCount
            FROM emp
            GROUP BY Ename
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1' ,
@subject = 'Count of Employee Names',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 0
```

Comment: I'd suggest you get my custom stored procedure at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/DB_Mail/107006/, which will let you put the results of the query into an html table within the email - much neater looking.